# How to return actual dom elements from a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, return

I have a an object stored in local storage. This object has a property whose value is an array or a string depending on user interaction. Now I have a function that transforms each item of the array into an anchor with a specific hash value. I append the anchors to dynamically created span. I then try to return the span. But it outputs `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. I know I can solve this problem by appending the links to an already existing Dom element but I want the anchors displayed next to the 'recommendations' string in the code below:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var allResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allResults');
        for (i = 0; i < allResults.length; i++) {
          $(" <div class = 'resultStat'> </div >").html(
            "Lesson Name: " + allResults[i].name + "<ul><li> score:" + allResults[i].score + "</li><li>  Recommendations:" + links(allResult[i].recom) + "</li></ul>"
          ).appendTo('.main);            function links(item){              if(item[0]==null){             
            b = item;
          }
          else {
            anchors = document.createElement('a');
            anchors.innerText = item;
            anchors.href = "blabla.html" + " #" + item;
            b = document.createElement('span');
            b.appendChild(anchors);
          }
          return b;
        }
```

This is an example of allResults  above:

[{name:force, scores :"100%", time:"0m 44s", freq":1,recom:[]}, {name: "Force",  scores: "0%",  time: "0m 2s",freq:13, recom: ["module1","module2","module3","module4"]}]

I would appreciate it more if a solution is given in vanilla js.

Comment: Please don't use inline code for such a big block of code -> [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please make this an actual [mcve] (inlcuding relevant markup and JS without typos)

Comment: object `[object HTMLSpanElement]` is a valid DOM element. When you print this on console you get `[object HTMLSpanElement]` as it is displayed as string. The same behaviour you get when you print js object `{}` in console which gets printed as `[Object Object]`. Try `console.dir` to print the actual DOM tree

Comment: Am not trying to print in console but to actually print in an actual HTML document

Comment: Thanks for the update. See my updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry for posting a badly formatted code. I tried as much as possible to write something good with my mobile but its not working. I tried writing it on my editor and posting it here but the result was worse. I had tried many times and by the time of the actual post I was already tired. Thanks for all your help. Was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the function returns the element, it is being added to the string. So the element object is converted to a string hence why you see the `[object HTMLSpanElement]`.

You can easily avoid this by using the `outerHTML` property of an element which will return its content as a string.

I rewrote the code in VanillaJS.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const data = [{name:'force', scores: "100%", time: "0m 44s", freq: 1, recom:[]}, {name: 'Force', scores: "0%", time: "0m 2s",freq:13, recom: ["module1","module2","module3","module4"]}];

addEventListener('load', _ => {
  let allResults = data || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allResults'));

  allResults.forEach(allResult => {
    const resultStat = Object.assign(document.createElement('resultStat'), {
      className: 'resultStat',
      innerHTML: `Lesson Name: ${allResult.name}<ul>
          <li>Score: ${allResult.scores}</li>
          <li>Recommendations: ${links(allResult.recom)}</li></ul>`
    });

    main.append(resultStat);
  });
});

function links(items) {
  let b = document.createElement('span');
  if (!Array.isArray(items)) items = [items];
  items.forEach(item => {
    const anchor = Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {
      innerText: item,
      href: `blabla.html#${item}`
    });

    b.append(anchor);
  });

  return b.outerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Better with b.textContent  =  items;  and also enclose the block of code after the if statement so that it does not throw up an error when items is a string. I tried editing your code but its not working on my mobile

Comment: I meant Put it in an else block.

Comment: The if statement, is to check if the `item` is not an array, so that the `forEach` loop won't throw an error. There isn't need for the `else` block... If you still don't understand let me know. @PeterOrji

Comment: I ran the code on chrome and trebedit it only worked when it was enclosed in an else block

Comment: On trebedit it said that    Items.forEach  is not a function (type error) whenever items was a string I don't know if you get my point?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are mixing jQuery and DOM in a not recommended manner
2. You have invalid code, not quoting your HTML strings and missing a `)` in your parse statement
3. You have typos, scores instead of score
4. You have a function inside a loop - that is incorrect

Perhaps you meant to do this - please post an example of the object to get a better answer

```js
const allResults = [{name:"Force", scores :"100%", time:"0m 44s", freq:1,recom:[]}, 
{name: "Force", scores: "0%", time: "0m 2s",freq:13, recom: ["module1","module2","module3","module4"]}]
const links = strOrArr => {
  if (strOrArr === null) return "";
  const arr = !Array.isArray(strOrArr) ? [strOrArr] : strOrArr;
  if (arr.length ===0) return ""
  return `<li>Recommendations: 
    ${arr.map(rec => `<span><a href="blabla.html#${rec}">${rec}</a></span>`).join(" ")}
  </li>`
};
$(function() { // jQuery onload
  // const allResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allResults'));
  $(".main").append(
    allResults.map(res => $("<div/>")
      .addClass("resultStat")
      .html(`Lesson Name: ${res.name}  <ul><li> score: ${res.scores}</li>${links(res.recom)}</ul>`)
    )
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"></div>
```

Comment: I think OP want to create a Div class="resultStat" for every localStorage Item instead of append all ul inside a single Div class="resultStat".